# Custom array macro not working as intended

Tags: arrays, c, macos

I wanted to make a custom array in C like std::array in C++. However the following code doesn't work.

array.h:

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_ARRAY
#define CUSTOM_ARRAY


    #define array(T, name, n_elements) do { \
        T name [(n_elements)]; \
    } while(0)



#endif
```

main.c:

```
#include "array.h"
#include <stdio.h>



int main()
{
    array(int, array_name, 5);

    size_t size_of_array = sizeof(array_name) / sizeof(array_name[0]);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++) {
        array_name[i] = i;
        printf("%d\n", array_name[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It displays the following errors message:

`main.c: In function 'main': main.c:10:35: error: 'array_name' undeclared (first use in this function) 10 |     size_t size_of_array = sizeof(array_name) / sizeof(array_name[0]); |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~ main.c:10:35: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in`

But in main.c, doesn't the array in the macro expand into:

```
int array_name[5];
```

Comment: You placed the declaration from the macro inside a block (delimted by `{}`).  So it's no longer in scope after the end of that block, where you try to use it.

Comment: The macro expansion also includes do-while, which limits the variable visibility.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Then what if I want to make the macro expand into a regular statement. Is there any other way I can do that apart from do {} while(0)?

Comment: Remove the do-while, leaving only `T name [(n_elements)];`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I meant something else. If I want to add more things to the macro in the future and then I want to use it in an if-statement that doesn't contain {}. Then only the first statement in the macro will expand into the if-statement. So I asked if there was a solution to this if I can't use a do{} while(0).

Comment: Don't invent evil macros like this. This is not how you do type-generic programming in C. If you want a type-generic array when invent one through some opaque type design.

Comment: The point of this? You seek to make a data definition look like a function call... The only consequence is that the reader would have to seek out your "macro", then turn, scratch their head, and mutter, "WTF?"... `int arrayName[5];` is both conventional and more brief.

Comment: @Fe2O3 This was just an exercise for me. To get more used to macros.

Comment: @Lundin Could you give a link on how to do this? Or an explanation?

Comment: Consider what `do { } while()` will mean if one wanted to instantiate an object at file scope.

Comment: @user20598969 [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888) And then design a "ADT"/"class" based on that technique.

Answer (score 0):

You are limiting the scope of the array to that one statement.

Replace

```c
#define array(T, name, n_elements) do { \
    T name [(n_elements)]; \
} while(0)
```

with

```c
#define array( T, name, n_elements ) T name[ n_elements ]
```